# Load only required plugin into the Schema when saving a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Plugins is quite a powerful feature in Mongoose.js, but there is one thing I have got stuck with. I need to load only the required plugin into the Schema when saving a model. Because If I don't do it, the other unnecessary plugins are loaded automatically along with lots of validation errors.

Here is my schema

```
// models/user_collection.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    role: String // either 'memeber' or 'admin'
});

// Member User Plugin
UserSchema.plugin(function (schema) {
    schema.add({
        locality: { type: String, required: true },
        contactNo: { type: Number, min: 13, max: 13 }
    });
});

// Admin User Plugin
UserSchema.plugin(function (schema) {
    schema.add({
        accountNo: { type: String, required: true },
        settingsArray: Array
    });
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Now whenever I try to save a record only for member user, the Schema automatically loads the Admin plugin, responding with validation errors.

So,

```
var member = new User();
member.username = 'XYZ';
member.password = createHash('ABC') // a hashing method;
member.role = 'member';
member.locality = 'USA';
member.contactNo = 123456;
member.save(function(err, user) {
   if(err) { console.log(err); res.send(err); return; }
   // if successful I do my stuff
});
```

As soon as the save method is executed, I get validation errors from Admin like
"accountNo is required", ( I am not gonna paste the stack trace here, it will get messy, but you got the point )

Now I know that it is not an issue or bug with Mongoose.js, but I am doing something wrong here. Can you guys please guide me how to do it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are applying both the plugins to the same schema. So all the plugin functionality is being added to the schema. So `accountNo` and `locality` is required. Plugins are used to define common code at one place and use it across different schemas.

The way you have used plugins here, you just have broken down the definition of the model to smaller parts. You could as well put everything under the schema and would have gotten the same effect.

Read about [plugins](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) again.

As you said, I guess Discriminators is the way to go.

Comment: My bad, I actually read the documentation upside down. The thing I need can by achieved by Discriminators in Mongoose, which is like an inheritance. A module mongoose-schema-extends already does that, but a/c to most developers it's obsolete now. Well the module is sexier than Discriminators.